# calcloc.distanceTo() throwing a null pointer exception

Tags: android, gps, nullpointerexception, location, distance

```
 String calculateDistanceMetric(double loclat, double loclong)
    {      
        Log.i("Metric", String.valueOf(loclat));
        Log.i("Metric", String.valueOf(loclong));
        Location destloc = new Location(provider);
        destloc.setLatitude(loclat);
        destloc.setLongitude(loclong);
        Log.i("Metric", "1");
        if (calcloc.distanceTo(destloc) > 100) ////////here is where the code breaks
        {
            Log.i("Metric", "2");
            float round = calcloc.distanceTo(destloc);
            Log.i("Metric", "3");
            DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.#");
            Log.i("Metric", "4");
            distanceUnit = "KM";
            Log.i("Metric", "5");
            return String.valueOf(round/1000);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("Metric", "6");
            distanceUnit = "Meters";
            Log.i("Metric", "7");
            return String.valueOf(calcloc.distanceTo(destloc)); 
            }

    }
```

why do  I get nullpointerexception?
the values for loclat and loclong are valid, destloc is initialized, I ran out of ideas on why this is causing it to crash.
Also, if possibile suggest other ways of calculating distance between two points (I already know of distanceBetween)

Comment: Where had you define and declare `calcloc`?

Comment: Post your exception StarckTrace from LogCat output, to know where exactly is the error.

Comment: i did declare it, im sure of that

Comment: decided to use distanceBetween, thanks for the answers

Comment: post stacktrace or something

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize your `calcloc` variable (which is obviously not the case so far).

Comment: You definitely declared it (otherwise you would get a compilation error). But you obviously did not assign a value to it.

Comment: i didnt, i just assigned a latitude and a longitude to it.

Comment: Ok. `destloc` is correctly initialized with your latitude/longitude. But how did you initialize `calcloc` ?

Comment: calcloc = new Location(provider)

Comment: so it's not representing any particular location ?

Comment: What location do you expect it to represent ?

Comment: that is the thing. I don't know what it is representing. I want to use distanceBetween